# Entering inputs during a for-loop

Tags: python, for-loop, range

So I am trying to make it so I can input a float after each on of the print commands go through. (This might be unclear but is easily clarified by looking at the code.)

My current code

```
def getFloats(x):
    for i in range(1,x+1):
        print("Enter float ",i," : ",),input()

def main():
    numFloats=int(input("Enter the number if list elements: "))
    getFloats(numFloats)

main()
```

The current output:

```
Enter the number if list elements: 3
Enter float  1  : 
23.3
Enter float  2  : 
25.6
Enter float  3  : 
29.6
```

What I want the output to be:

```
Enter the number if list elements: 3
Enter float  1  : 23.3
Enter float  2  : 25.6
Enter float  3  : 29.6
```

Comment: You can pass a string to `input()`, use string formatting for that.

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
input("Enter float %d : "%i)
```

instead of `print("Enter float ",i," : ",),input()`

Or if you're asking how to `print` without a *newline* anyway, use `end=''`:

```
print("Enter float ",i," : ", end='')
```